# plotting without display: correct use of matplotlib.use()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot on a system that doesn't have a display.
If I plot naively using matplotlib.pyplot.plt I get

```
    raise RuntimeError('Invalid DISPLAY variable')
```

I have found out that `matplotlib.use()` can be used in this context.
Now I have a main file:

```
 **main.py:**

 import my_module
 ....
 # do stuff

 **my_module.py:**

 import matplotlib
 matplotlib.use('Agg') # Must be before importing matplotlib.pyplot or     pylab!
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
 # do stuff
 plt.plot(data)
```

When running main.py I get:

```
UserWarning: 
This call to matplotlib.use() has no effect because the backend has already
been chosen; matplotlib.use() must be called *before* pylab,     matplotlib.pyplot,
or matplotlib.backends is imported for the first time.
```

But to me it seems I am calling it before importing `pyplot`. Later I get this runtime error

```
File "[OMIT]/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib    /backends/backend_qt5.py", line 144, in _create_qApp
raise RuntimeError('Invalid DISPLAY variable')
RuntimeError: Invalid DISPLAY variable
```

So what is the right way to change `matplotlib` backend?I do not need a display, but I need to be able to store the figures using plt.savefig

Comment: Is there anything else in `main.py` that could be importing `matplotlib`? Do you import any other modules other than `my_module`?

Comment: I just changed my code to have my_module imported first. thanks for the suggestion. Problem still there without refreshing the kernel

Comment: Problem is still there after refreshing the console. Now the first import matplotlib is done in the first module imported by main.py, should be ok right?

Comment: Should be. Perhaps you need to create a [MCVE] for your question to get a proper answer on here.

Comment: will do shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

on a fresh kernel, especially if you are using `ipython`, before importing `matplotlib.pyplot`

I'd be curious, and happy, to know if there are ways to clear/flush the ipython kernel, without having to restart it; so far, my quest has not been successful.

Comment: I am trying with %reset right now (Anaconda,iPython)

Comment: Please let me know. ;)

Comment: %reset didn't work, now trying to restart the kernel

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I have solved by:

```
**main.py***
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg') # Must be before importing matplotlib.pyplot or pylab!
import my_module
```

as the many subimports in `my_module` made impossible to identify where pyplot was first imported.
Also I have done:

```
import my_module
```

instead of that I was doing ealier.

```
from my_module import my_func
```